# How to keep two tables with diff. datasources inside a rectanguler in one page in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have two tables inside a rectangle in ssrs report ...

The two tables having completely diff. data sources and completely diff. ...

Now I am grouping my report Monthly .

If I choose month I need to get the report for all the dates in that month in individual pages .

suppose if I take feb 2017 it should give 28 pages with each page should have

I want my output like bellow

page 1          page 2           ..... page 28

Table 1         table 1 ..... table 1

Table 2         table 2 ..... table 2

but I am getting result like

page 1   page 2  ..... page 28

Table 1  table 1 ..... table 1

page 29   page 30  ..... page n

Table 2   table 2 ..... table 2

Hope understand my query ..

please help ...

Comment: Are you saying you want table 1 and table 2 on the same page but on other pages is the next table 1 and table 2. Might be best to give a mock up.

Comment: yes that is correct .. I have date column in both tables .. if suppose I choose feb month .. I need the table 1 table 2 to be come under each page on that date wise ..

Comment: You need to put the tables into their own sub report. Have them accept the date parameter. Then put the two reports into a table that is grouped by the date. And send that date through to the sub reports. I've done this before but can't seem to find the reference I used. Will keep looking.